# how we can use inbuilt policy's in azure via terraform , i am finding code for only custom policy's , i am using below is this correct?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

```
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = "true"

  version = "3.0.1"

  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_policy_assignment" "auditvms" { 
  name = "audit-vm-manageddisks"

  resource_id = "/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg-prod-hub"

  policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/06a78e20-9358-41c9-923c-fb736d382a4d"

  description = "Shows all virtual machines not using managed disks"

  display_name = "Audit VMs without managed disks assignment" 
}
```

```
Error : │ Error: ID cannot be a Resource Group ID
│ 
│   with azurerm_resource_policy_assignment.auditvms,
│   on main.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_resource_policy_assignment" "auditvms":
│   11:  resource_id = "/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg-prod-hub"
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use a different resource id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here resource_id is  the ID of the Resource or its scope, where this
> has to be actually  applied. This forces a new Resource Policy
> Assignment to be created on that resource.

***I have tried to reproduce the same .
Have given resourcegroup Id for resource Id and got the same error:  `Error: ID cannot be a Resource Group ID`***

---

[image]

---

- So if you are trying to set policy for resource group ( *as you have
  resourceid looks like for  resource group*), Then for a Resource
  Group use the ***`azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment`*** .

***Example:***

- *If your resource is Subscription use the ***`azurerm_subscription_policy_assignment`*** as resource .*

In your case if its for resource group ,Replace resource with **resource_group** (***even replace resource_id with resource_group_id***)

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment" "auditvms" { 
  name = "."
  resource_group_id = "/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rg-prod-hub"
  ……
}
```

- In case of particular resource , then resource_id must be the that
  particular azure resource id:

***For example*** :If  resource is Kubernetes cluser as snippet from [azurerm-resource-policy-assignment | https://shisho.dev](https://shisho.dev/dojo/providers/azurerm/Policy/azurerm-resource-policy-assignment/)

```
resource "azurerm_resource_policy_assignment" "policy_assignment" {
  name                 = "labeled-pods"
  resource_id          = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster.id
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.policy.id
 }
```

**Reference:**
[azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_policy_assignment)

Comment: hey ,thanks for this but how to pass parameters in to the script ,i have checked in the web but nothing supportable ,can you share any link to understand passing parameters.